# improve precision in text classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, text-mining, precision-recall

I am working on binary text classification using sklearn:

1. The length of each sample is not high (~ 200-500 characters)
2. I use TF-IDF to get important words as
   TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=False, max_df=0.5, stop_words='english', max_features = 5000)
3. SGDClassifier is used as:
   SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', alpha=.0001, n_iter=50, penalty="l2", shuffle=False , class_weight='auto')

The classifier shows good recall for both binary classes (~80%) but poor precision for class-1 (~40%). as in my application, precision is more important than recall I am wondering how can I improve precision even by slightly reducing recall? I don't obsess with SGDClassifier. Other classifiers are ok.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your system is too liberal.  If you can generate an ROC curve or have some kind of threshold based classifier (I am not sure how SGDClassifier works) you could simply make the voting scheme more conservative.  Assuming class-1 is "positive," you need to make more "negative" predictions perhaps by raising the threshold for classifying as "positive."  Doing this will necessarily raise the number of negatives and reduce the number of positives, which will improve precision at the cost of reduced recall.

Answer (score 0):

Try different classifiers and see if they are more accurate over all.

Try increasing the weights for data points in the class you care more about.

Try different features and see if they are more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Is your dataset balanced, do both classes have roughly the same number of subjects? If not, try class_weight='balanced'

Also check this answer to trade off recall for precision
[Classifier with adjustable precision vs recall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140266/classifier-with-adjustable-precision-vs-recall/188385#188385)